# PDO exception - Access denied

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a login system in PHP and I am getting an access denied error from my PDO. My credentials are correct so I am not sure what is causing this.

This is the exception

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)'

I've also checked the privileges in [phpMyAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhpMyAdmin) and everything looks correct.

***This is part of my code*** and hopefully someone sees something that I don't...

#### File *init.php*

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $GLOBALS['config'] = array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '******',
            'db' => '*****'
        ),
        'remember' => array(
            'cookie_name' => 'hash',
            'cookie_expiry' => 604800
        ),
        'session' => array(
            'session_name' => 'user'
        )
    );

    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });

    require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

#### File *Config.php*

```
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null){
        if($path){
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach($path as $bit){
                if(isset($config[$bit])){
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }

            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Part of my DB.php**

```
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo =
                new PDO(
                    'mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') .
                        ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'),
                    Config::get('mysql/username'),
                    Config::get('mysql/password'));

            echo 'Connected!';
        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
```

#### File *Index.php*

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
$user = DB::getInstance();
```

Comment: The error message is complaining that you're not logging in with a password (`using password: NO`). Have you tried debugging your `Config` class to see that it's returning the correct values to your `PDO` constructor?

Comment: Problem is in 'host' => '127.0.0.1', try to change it to localhost. Or there is some password to connect to database and you are providing nothing.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh i've tried both plus 127.0.0.1 IS localhost

Comment: @Phylogenesis that's what I am about to do now.

Comment: @Geo Looking into it more closely, it really does look like your `Config::get()` static method is not returning the values you want. That error has all the hallmarks of the MySQL PDO driver using the default host (localhost), username (current user) and password (none). Effectively running `new PDO('mysql:host=&dbname=', null, null)`.

Comment: Thanks @Phylogenesis I added each value manually in the PDO params and it worked. I just need to see why my Config was sending in wrong values or no values at all

Comment: You're building a login system and you're getting an access denied error. Irony is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Your static method in file *Config.php* is not iterating over the structure.

You are providing array('mysql/username') as the path, and it gets broken down to 'mysql' and 'username' for the foreach and the isset($config['mysql']) returns true and then $config is set to an array (with everything from 'mysql' key). And then you return the array and not the value you want.

```
        foreach($path as $bit){
            if(isset($config[$bit])){
                $config = $config[$bit]; // <-- Returns $config['mysql']
            }
        }
```